# Create data table containing all possible combinations of values from four lists

Tags: r, loops

I have the following four lists.

```
varnames <- list("beefpork", "breakfast", "breakfast_yn", "diet_soda", "food_label", "fruit_and_veggie", "fruit_juice", "fruits", "milk",                      "min_foods","regular_soda", "ssb", "total_fruit", "vegetables",                      "asthma", "bmiclass3", "bmiclass4","bmiclass5", "dental_absence",                     "dental_appt", "diabetes", "food_allergies", "sore_teeth", "trying_weight",                     "count_pa60days", "count_vigpa20days", "gaming_bedroom", "other_organized_pa", "pa30outdoor","paguidelines", "pc_time", "school_transport", "sport_teams", "tv_bedroom", "tv_time_char", "video_games_char")
grades <- list("2", "4", "8", "11")
groups <- list("none", "ethnic", "bordercounty")
regions <- list("state", "hsr")
```

And the following function, which returns an integer:

```
all_empty = function(outcome, groupvar, gradevar, regionvar){
  #How many observations?

  if (groupvar == "none") 
    fmla <- as.formula(paste0("~", outcome))
  else 
    fmla <- as.formula(paste0("~", outcome, "+", groupvar))

  if (regionvar == "hsr")
    mydata = span_phrwts
  else if (regionvar == "state" & groupvar %in% c("none", "ethnic"))
    mydata = span_statewts
  else if (regionvar == "state" & groupvar == "bordercounty")
    mydata = span_borderwts
  else mydata = span_statewts

  myrow = svytable(fmla, subset(mydata, grade==gradevar)) %>% nrow()
  return(myrow)
}
```

I'm trying to write a code that will run the function on all 864 possible combinations of the values from my lists, and create one data table with 864 rows and 5 columns.

I would like the final table to look something like this, but has not been successful:

```
Variable          Grade          Group           Region     Obs
beefpork          2              none            state      5
beefpork          4              none            state      5
beefpork          8              none            state      3
beefpork          11             none            state      0
```

This is my attempt to run this, but am unable to calculate the **rownum** correctly.

```
output_all <- matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = length(varnames)*length(grades)*length(groups)*length(regions))
for(l in 1:length(regions)) {
  for (k in 1:length(grades)) {
    for(j in 1:length(groups)) {
      for(i in 1:length(varnames)){
        rownum = i + ((length(groups)*length(grades)*length(regions)) - 1)
        output_all[rownum, 1] = varnames[[i]]
        output_all[rownum, 2] = groups[[j]]
        output_all[rownum, 3] = grades[[k]]
        output_all[rownum, 4] = regions[[l]]
        output_all[rownum, 5] = all_empty(varnames[[i]], groups[[j]], grades [[k]], regions[[l]])

      }
    }
  } 
}
output_all %>% as_data_frame() %>% View()
```

Any help/advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's ok to use vectors and not lists, `tidyr::crossing` seems like a straightforward approach.

```
varnames <- c("beefpork", "breakfast", "breakfast_yn", "diet_soda", "food_label", "fruit_and_veggie", "fruit_juice", "fruits", "milk",                      "min_foods","regular_soda", "ssb", "total_fruit", "vegetables",                      "asthma", "bmiclass3", "bmiclass4","bmiclass5", "dental_absence",                     "dental_appt", "diabetes", "food_allergies", "sore_teeth", "trying_weight",                     "count_pa60days", "count_vigpa20days", "gaming_bedroom", "other_organized_pa", "pa30outdoor","paguidelines", "pc_time", "school_transport", "sport_teams", "tv_bedroom", "tv_time_char", "video_games_char")
grades <- c("2", "4", "8", "11")
groups <- c("none", "ethnic", "bordercounty")
regions <- c("state", "hsr")


tidyr::crossing(varnames, grades, groups, regions)


# A tibble: 864 x 4
   varnames grades groups       regions
   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>        <chr>  
 1 asthma   11     bordercounty hsr    
 2 asthma   11     bordercounty state  
 3 asthma   11     ethnic       hsr    
 4 asthma   11     ethnic       state  
 5 asthma   11     none         hsr    
 6 asthma   11     none         state  
 7 asthma   2      bordercounty hsr    
 8 asthma   2      bordercounty state  
 9 asthma   2      ethnic       hsr    
10 asthma   2      ethnic       state
```

Comment: the first part works, but how do I apply my function to each row?

Comment: I think i found the answer. allvars$obs = mapply(all_empty, allvars$varnames, allvars$groups, allvars$grades, allvars$regions) seems to work

Answer (score 8):

Using `data.table` you have the function `CJ` to create the cross-join. Then we add a row num (Idx) to perform row-wise call of function. We finally remove the Idx column

```
library(data.table)
dt <- CJ(varnames=varnames,grades=grades,groups=groups,regions=regions)
dt[,Idx:=.I]
dt[,by=Idx, Obs:=all_empty(outcome, groupvar, gradevar, regionvar)]
dt[,Idx:=NULL]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider `expand.grid`, then call your function with `mapply` to pass column values elementwise to user-defined method.

```
varnames <- c("beefpork", "breakfast", "breakfast_yn", "diet_soda", 
              "food_label", "fruit_and_veggie", "fruit_juice", 
              "fruits", "milk", "min_foods", "regular_soda", 
              "ssb", "total_fruit", "vegetables", "asthma", 
              "bmiclass3", "bmiclass4","bmiclass5", "dental_absence",
              "dental_appt", "diabetes", "food_allergies", 
              "sore_teeth", "trying_weight", "count_pa60days", 
              "count_vigpa20days", "gaming_bedroom", "other_organized_pa", 
              "pa30outdoor","paguidelines", "pc_time", "school_transport", 
              "sport_teams", "tv_bedroom", "tv_time_char", "video_games_char")
grades <- c("2", "4", "8", "11")
groups <- c("none", "ethnic", "bordercounty")
regions <- c("state", "hsr")

df <- expand.grid(varnames=varnames, grades=grades, groups=groups, regions=regions,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 864 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ varnames: chr  "beefpork" "breakfast" "breakfast_yn" "diet_soda" ...
# $ grades  : chr  "2" "2" "2" "2" ...
# $ groups  : chr  "none" "none" "none" "none" ...
# $ regions : chr  "state" "state" "state" "state" ...
# ...

df$fmla <- ifelse(df$groups == "none", paste0("~", outcome), paste0("~", outcome, "+", groupvar))

df$mydata <- ifelse(df$regions == "hsr", "span_phrwts",
                    ifelse(df$regions == "state" & df$groups %in% c("none", "ethnic"), "span_statewts",
                           ifelse(df$regions == "state" & df$groups == "bordercounty", "span_borderwts", 
                                  "span_statewts")))
```

Function call

```
all_empty <- function(outcome, groupvar, gradevar, regionvar, fmla, mydata){
  # How many observations?
  myrow <- svytable(as.formula(fmla), subset(get(mydata), grade==gradevar))
  return(nrow(myrow))
}

df$Obs <- mapply(all_empty, df$varnames, df$groups, df$grades, 
                 df$regions, df$fmla, df$mydata)
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, the first part works, but I'm getting an error when I tried to call the function as you suggested, it runs but with warning messages, and the results didn't look right.  Here's the first warning message (In if (groupvar == "none") fmla <- as.formula(paste0("~", outcome)) else fmla <- as.formula(paste0("~",  : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used)

Comment: First, pass in vectors of your indicators and not lists into expand.grid. And second as you found above your function needs single values as parameters and not multiple sized vectors. Hence use `mapply` for elementwise values across columns into your method `all_empty`. You can even reduced your method's lines by creating new columns for *fmla* and *mydata* conditionally with `ifelse` and pass those as two more params into `mapply` using `as.formula` and `get` from string values. See edit.